# how to pass header and body together in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http

In angular how to pass header and body together in one put request,

```
     const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': this.login.token
      }),
      body: {'fiToDelete': id}
    };
     return this.httpClient.put('https://admin.chatomate.dev.gradlesol.com/app/fi/delete', httpOptions).subscribe();
```

this method is not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the `body` part from the options and put it separately as the second argument inside the request.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': this.login.token
  }),
 
};
 return this.http.put(url,  body: {'fiToDelete': id}, httpOptions).subscribe();
```

Another note, it seems you're trying to `delete` with a `Put` request. You might like to change it to a `DELETE` request.